# Populate INPUT & SELECT with JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, forms, select, input

Hi I am attempting to populate not only input fields from a JSON response, but also the value that the select box has.  I can get all the input fields to populate accordingly but I cant seem to integrate populating the select field as well.  If I only have a select field I can get it to populate no problem, but how to get the script to populate both inputs and select with the appropriate data? Any guidance would be appreciated.

here is the html snippet of the field elements:

```
Email <input type="text" style="width:75%;" name="rEmail" id="rEmail" class="roomForm" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com">

Status <select name="rStatus" id="rStatus"><option value="Disabled">Disabled</option><option value="Enabled">Enabled</option></select>
```

My script below populates the inputs fields, and I commented out the select append due to the fact that it was just adding everything in the JSON to the list, rather than just the data for the select.

```
            $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"getroomfields.php?id="+row_id,success:function(result){
            var json = $.parseJSON(result);
                var $select = $('#rStatus');
                //$select.find('option').remove();
                for(key in json[0]){
                if(json[0].hasOwnProperty(key))
                    $('input[name='+key+']').val(json[0][key]);
                //  $select.append('<option value=' + key + ' selected>' + json[0][key] + '</option>');
                }
                }
            }); // end ajax
```

Thank you kindly in advance!

Here is the JSON:

```
[{
    "rID": "1",
    "rName": "Test 123 Co",
    "rLocation": "Anywhere, World",
    "rContact": "John Doe",
    "rPhone": "555-555-5555",
    "rEmail": "test@someplace.com",
    "rStatus": "Enabled",
    "rAdded": "05-03-2018"
}]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your json?

Comment: Sure thing one sec and I will include, thank you!

Comment: Added in original post above.

Comment: you have to check if `key` is the same as the id attribute of your select element before attempting to append a value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `select` options already exist, I'm not sure why you are trying to add anything. `.val()` works for dropdowns just like inputs.

I removed some unnecessary code and changed your selector so it doesn't specify only `input`s.

```
for (var key in json[0]) {
  if (json[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    $('[name=' + key + ']').val(json[0][key]);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vLb89bas/

You could also select by id: `$('#' + key)`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that... I was going round in circles lol ... /smacks_forehead.  =p Thank you so much, you rock!